# A strict inequality between grades

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

In *Steps in Commutative Algebra* by R. Y. Sharp this exercise (16.28) is raised:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $I=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^2∩(x_1)$ in the ring  $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ of polynomials over $K$ in the indeterminates $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Let $R=K[x_1,x_2,x_3]/I$, and let $P$ denote the prime ideal $ (x_1,x_2)/I$ of the Noetherian ring $R$. Show that:
>   (a) $\operatorname{grade}P=0,$ and
>   (b) $\operatorname{grade}_{R_P}PR_P>0.$

(a) is obvious since all the elements of $P$ are zero-divisors. I want a proof for (b) please! This proves that the well-known inequality $\operatorname{grade} PR_P≥\operatorname{grade}P$ could be strict.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $I=(X_1^2, X_1X_2,X_1X_3)$. Set $S=K[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ and $\mathfrak p=(X_1,X_2)$. Then $IS_{\mathfrak p}=X_1S_{\mathfrak p}$ (since $X_3$ is invertible in $S_{\mathfrak p}$), and $R_P\simeq S_{\mathfrak p}/IS_{\mathfrak p}\simeq K[X_2,X_3]_{(X_2)}$ whose depth is one.